# react router not working and no erros in console or compilation error is shown [ react router dom v5]

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Until now the router was working perfectly fine but suddenly it isn't working. I'm totally confused and I haven't done any kind of upgrades.

The router doesn't render the components itself. I wonder if even the correct route gets rendered based on path.

Only the first route is working fine, the other two don't seem to work.

AssetPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AssetNavBar from "./AssetNavBar";
import "./assets.css";

function AssetPage() {
  return (
    <div className="top-div">
  <header>
    <AssetNavBar />
  </header>
  <main className="main-flex">
    <Route path="/assets/add" exact><h1>in main</h1></Route>
    <Route path="/assets/storage">
      <h1>in storage</h1>
    </Route>
      <Route path="/assets/view">
      <h1>in view</h1>
      </Route>
    </main>
   </div>
   );
 }

  export default AssetPage;
```

AssetNavBar.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

 function AssetNavBar() {
  return (
   <div>
     <nav>
      <ul className="ul-side-by-side">
        <li>
        <Link to="/assets/add">add assets</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/assets/view">view assets</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/assets/storage">storage</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
     </nav>
   </div>
 );
 }
 export default AssetNavBar;
```

index.js - [starting point]

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import SingleItem from "./components/inventory/SingleItem"
import HomeNavBar from "./components/HomeNavBar";
import InventoryPage from "./components/inventory/InventoryPage";
import ProductPage from "./components/products/ProductPage";
import PurchasePage from "./components/purchase/PurchasePage";
import SupplierPage from "./components/supplier/SupplierPage";
import AssetPage from "./components/assetFolder/AssetPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='horizontal-div-boxes'>
      <header>
        <HomeNavBar/>
      </header>
      <main className="main-flex">
        <Route path="/dashboard">
          <SingleItem />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/inventory'>
          <InventoryPage/>
        </Route>
        <Route path='/purchase'>
          <PurchasePage/>
        </Route>
        <Route path='/products/add'>
          <ProductPage/>
        </Route>
        <Route path='/suppliers/add'>
         <SupplierPage/>
        </Route>
        <Route path='/assets/add'>
            <AssetPage/>
        </Route>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

version

```
└─┬ react-router-dom@5.3.0       
  └── react-router@5.2.1
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code? Can we see where any router component is rendering these two components? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Are you sure there are no errors? Are you sure of the installed version of `react-router-dom`? From your project directory run `npm list react-router react-router-dom` and report back the installed version.

Comment: Had you run `npm i` recently? It could be the reason for updating the react-router-dom package. As mentioned by Drew in above comment, please confirm the installed version.

Comment: No I did not run any configuration/update commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `AssetPage` component is rendered on a `"/assets/add"` path and there are no other `"/assets*"` paths, so the other two links don't link to any routes that render content.

```
<Route path='/assets/add'>
  <AssetPage />
</Route>
```

In other words, when you link to `"/assets/view"` or `"/assets/storage"` the path no longer matches `"/assets/add"` and the `AssetPage` component is unmounted.

## Solution

I am sure that you want this root route to be just `"/assets"` to allow further matching any `"/assets*"` paths.

```
<Route path='/assets'>
  <AssetPage />
</Route>
```